# How to use Fiddler2 along with Windows 7 and HTTPs?

Tags: windows-7, https, fiddler

I have noticed that Fiddler2 does not work with https in windows 7 as in windows Xp. Probably resigning option does not work due to windows 7 better security.

When accessing https site with this option on, the page either hangs, or https traffic just not seen in Fiddler.

Is it possible to resolve this issue?

Thnx.

Comment: Note: The opener has answered his own question.

Answer (score 2):

That was my antivirus interference (Kaspersky Internet Security)

Answer (score 0):

Check your version....

Then go to the menu under Tools-Fiddler Options-HTTPS (tab) and choose to decrypt https traffic.

Comment: This method works in XP but not in Seven as I said...